# Highlight Words in a text, based on a list of keywords

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a google doc. There is a paragraph in the first part. Below is a table with keywords. I want to highlight words similar to the keywords in the table in the paragraph.
I wrote the following script. But it was not successful.

this code part uses get keyword from the table
var keywords = [];

```
function getKeywordsFromTable() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var tables = doc.getTables();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < table.getNumRows(); j++) {
      var row = table.getRow(j);
      for (var k = 0; k < row.getNumCells(); k++) {
        var cell = row.getCell(k);
        var text = cell.getText();
        keywords = keywords.concat(text.split(" ")); // split the text by space and add it to the keywords array
      }
    }
  }
  
  Logger.log(keywords); // you can check the keywords array in the log
}
```

Try this code part using highlight keywords in paragraph

```
function hlKwInPara() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.getText();
  var paragraphs = text.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
      var keyword = keywords[j];
      var keywordStart = paragraphs[i].indexOf(keyword);
      if (keywordStart !== -1) {
        var keywordEnd = keywordStart + keyword.length;
        body.replaceText(keyword, "<b>" + keyword + "</b>", {matchCase: true});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I will publish part of the sample file. [See this link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSjqNmQYsDCf13ta5LZFv70nEixyQHdG5hIqrHL2TX6j5M6sikX16mGhvMlZeBIc6SQcXgicjqphNz7/pub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- About `I want to highlight words similar to the keywords in the table in the paragraph.`, from your showing script, I understood that you wanted to replace the texts in the paragraphs with the words in the tables. For example, you want to replace `sample` with `<b>sample</b>`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script of `getKeywordsFromTable()`, `keywords` is not declared.
- I thought that in this case, it might be able to scan each paragraph.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getKeywordsFromTable() {
  var keywords = [];
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var tables = doc.getTables();
  for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < table.getNumRows(); j++) {
      var row = table.getRow(j);
      for (var k = 0; k < row.getNumCells(); k++) {
        var cell = row.getCell(k);
        var text = cell.getText();
        keywords = keywords.concat(text.split(" ")); // split the text by space and add it to the keywords array
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(keywords); // you can check the keywords array in the log
  return keywords;
}

// Please run this function.
function myFunction() {
  const words = [...new Set(getKeywordsFromTable())].map(e => e.trim());
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  words.forEach(t => {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
      const c = body.getChild(i);
      if (c.getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        c.asParagraph().replaceText(t, "<b>" + t + "</b>");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the texts in the paragraphs are replaced with the words in the tables like `<b>sample</b>`.

#### Note:

- If your expected `highlight` of `I want to highlight words` is to change the background color of words, please test `myFunction` as follows.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const words = [...new Set(getKeywordsFromTable())].map(e => e.trim());
    const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    words.forEach(t => {
      let word = body.findText(t);
      while (word) {
        const e = word.getElement();
        const start = word.getStartOffset();
        if (e.getParent().getParent().getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CELL) {
          e.asText().setBackgroundColor(start, word.getEndOffsetInclusive(), '#00FFFF');
        }
        word = body.findText(t, word);
      }
    });
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: wow...! it's working nicely. `<b>sample</b>` I used this section to bold the keyword and replace it.